# How to change the "ADC->HTR" value with a variable

Tags: stm32

I have a question about STM32 & Kiel.

in my project i can change the ADC analog watchdog HTR & LTR registers with direct number same as below:

ADC1->HTR =(500);

but when i try to assign a variable to this register same as below:

ADC1->HTR = (ADC_HVAL);

i have error:

../Src/main.c(120): error:  #513: a value of type "uint32_t *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "uint32_t"

I change the variable type but the error remain.

please help me
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need type-casting to set the variable. Just assign the value of the pointer.

```
ADC1->HTR = (*ADC_HVAL);
```

Comment: thanks for answer. can i have another question please?